# How to print more than 32 values?

Tags: googletest

Anyone know how to print more than 32 values? My output looks like this, and I'm trying to make it show the rest of the array:

```
Value of: model.GetOutput(0)
Expected: contains 64 values, where each value and its corresponding value in { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, ... } are an almost-equal pair
  Actual: { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... }, where the value pair (1, 2) at index #1 don't match, which is 1 from 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard-coded in the Google Test sources (`kMaxCount = 32`). To change it, you have to modify the code and rebuild Google Test. You might be able to [define your own printer](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values) if the type is specific enough.